# Create interactive plots R-plots on website

Tags: php, r, web, interactive

Last year I was working on a project concerning the creation of R-graphics. I remember that, during my research then, I came across something to visualize interactive R-graphics on a webpage. Unfortunately, I don't remember the name.

Does anyone know a good package/... to achieve this? I would like to get data from a database,  use this data to generate a plot using R, and then visualize the plot on a webpage.

Comment: shiny can be used for this.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was exactly the thing I found back then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. You could either use an direct method or an indirect method. For the indirect method you generate the javascript in your R script and pas it on to PHP (which is a lot of work but gives really nice graphs):

**direct method**

- [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)    - compatible with R-studio
- [GridSVG](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFUQFjAF&url=https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/gridSVG/gridsvg.pdf&ei=LqT4UpycBYaT0QXY54CICQ&usg=AFQjCNG4r_NFvbVXYGUTlVVP1lY_jc839w&bvm=bv.60983673,d.d2k&cad=rja)
- [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.org/)    - compatible with R-studio

**Indirect**

- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)
- [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/)

Personally I'm most excited about [epivizr](https://github.com/epiviz/epivizr) which makes use of D3.js

Comment: Thanks for the different possibilities. I will look into them right away!

Comment: @Mehdi Nellen. I wonder, do you have any example of indirect method?

Comment: @Mehdi Nellen: 3D.js or D3.js ?

Comment: @and D3.js, thanks